# Does Google Analytics' real-time reports delay in deducting leaving visitors?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm testing Google Analytics' accuracy with my newly built website.

Only about 2 seconds after I visit my website, I see the number of "active users on site" increases (in Google Analytics' real-time reports). So the increase in number is quite accurate.

But when it comes to deducting leaving visitors, I find it quite inaccurate. After I leave my website, the number takes about 5 minutes to decrease.

Is that normal or I missed some steps when installing Google Analytics?

Comment: There is no way that GA can know you have left your site in real-time.

Comment: @closetnoc But why does it know that after about 5 minutes?

Comment: No additional activity. It is an assumption.

Comment: It sounds like 5 minutes might be your average session duration.

Comment: Thanks closetnoc. @Stephen Ostermiller What does "session duration" mean in this case?

Comment: GA has a help document where they define it: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1006253?hl=en